# SQL Crash using semicolons and apostrophes

Tags: sql, sql-server, crash, ssms

I usually have multiple tabs open at the same time. I also have SQL panes from opening tables directly. It happens often that in my hurried typing, I execute a select statement and accidentally use a semicolon instead of an apostrophe (who decided to put those keys next to each other anyway?) or I execute it a nanosecond before typing the closing apostrophe. Of course this crashes my entire instance of SQL, and I lose all everything I was doing on the other tabs.

This is probably a dumb question, but is there a way to stop the crashes, aside from me typing correctly in the first place?

```
Application Name:   SqlWb.exe
Application Version:    2005.90.4060.0
Application Timestamp:  4d826c90
Fault Module Name:  vdt80.dll
Fault Module Version:   8.0.50727.1826
Fault Module Timestamp: 480d6e41
Exception Offset:   0032ae42
Exception Code: c0000409
Exception Data: 00000000
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Additional Information 1:   31a8
Additional Information 2:   31a8d36109bc8f4df442fa2e6255122a
Additional Information 3:   3857
Additional Information 4:   3857f10478be418059bb6c2b00dfb3db
```

Comment: What program is it that's crashing?  Or do you mean the server crashes?

Comment: Sorry - Mcrosoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Does it report the crashes?  Give you any debug info?  Sounds like you'd want to report these errors to Microsoft and see what they say.  Not a whole lot anyone here can do about it with the information you've provided.  Personally I've found SQL Server tools to be pretty stable.

Comment: You can try turn off IntelliSence in Tools->Options->TextEditor->Transact-SQL

Answer (score 0):

I was running the 2005 SSMS because of the 2008 annoyances. After installing the 2008 SSMS, it turns out I get an error message instead of a complete crash. It's an extra step every time I open a table, but at least I won't lose my work.